# How can I set my site root from: localhost/mysite/ to: localhost/mysite/view/ via htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost, mvc

hi just wondering if this is possible, when you access my default site directory `localhost/mysite` I want to set the path to render `localhost/mysite/view/` all my HTML pages will be rendered here just like a PHP MVC structure can do...  is it possible with htacces?

I'm an absolute newbie so I apologize if you find this question somehow stupid.

Comment: It's not stupid so much as incomprehensible.  I really have no idea what you want to achieve.  Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly this should be in the parent directories .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
# redirect to the view folder
RewriteRule    (.*) view/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this should be in the .htaccess file in the view folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# check to make sure this isn't a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you place it in htaccess you will definitely have a rewrite loop with "500 Internal Server Error" displayed to the user.

Comment: Good point @LazyOne,  That's what I get for not actually testing my solution.  :-)  I think the revised solution should work.